# selenium with brave implementation

Tags: selenium

Is there a way to Brave (Chromium web browser) browser directly as driver for Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
driver=wd.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/brave')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /snap/bin/brave unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

brave does open but `driver` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but here's how I got it to work. I didn't get the driver issue and I was able to open Brave using Selenium.  Notice that in the argument that I included the letter 'r' and backslashes.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"XXXXXX\XXXX\brave.exe")